# Should 20,000 data points provide a significant difference in confidence level over 300?

Tags: confidence-interval, history

I built an automated trading system and am experiencing better results during backtesting than during real trading using the strategy I developed.

During backtesting my strategy results in 300 trades over a three year time period. 65% (195) of those win.

I'm thinking that my strategy is failing during real trading due to a poor confidence level provided by my backtesting. Is 300 trades really enough to prove that a strategy works?

I am now thinking that perhaps I should target a 62% win rate over a ten year period (rather than 65% over just three years). This gives me 20,000 trades (12,400 that win).

Should 20,000 data points (trades) in theory provide a significant increase in confidence level?

Comment: You should just read this http://www.ams.org/notices/201405/rnoti-p458.pdf  "Pseudo-Mathematics and Financial Charlatanism: The Effects of Backtest Overfitting on Out-of-Sample Performance".

Comment: Thank you for the link. Skimming this paper, my understanding is that the author is saying overfitting can occur with too small a set of data, but with a large enough set of data, overfitting can be avoided -- is this correct? And if I am interpreting things correctly, then based on figure 2, it seems that 10 years of data could be adequate.

Comment: Try reading the paper carefully rather than just skimming.  Evaluating performance on the same data set used to build the trading strategy is not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more data points will result in a higher confidence level in the results.

That said, a higher confidence level in the results of an automated training program will *by no means* result in a more predictive forward-looking model.

That is, even given a perfect model of past trades (or a trading strategy that wins in back-testing), the lessons learned may not apply to future markets, or may have already been learned by participants, affecting the market movements in ways that invalidate the expected returns of the model or strategy.

A couple of (seminal if argumentative) works which illustrate these concepts more fully as they apply to markets are:

[A Random Walk Down Wall Street](http://www.worldcat.org/title/random-walk-down-wall-street-the-time-tested-strategy-for-successful-investing/oclc/50919959)

and

[Efficient Capital Markets: A Review of Theory and Empirical Work](http://efinance.org.cn/cn/fm/Efficient%20Capital%20Markets%20A%20Review%20of%20Theory%20and%20Empirical%20Work.pdf)